# Kivy events are scheduled too early

Tags: python, kivy, scheduler, event-loop

Python 3.7  Kivy 1.11.1  OSX 10.14.6

Im am writing a Kivy app with 25 fps that should have a fast event loop with 10ms. The problem is that the loop is called *much* faster - almost instantly. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my test code:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.read("config.ini")
Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '25')
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'free_all')
Config.write()

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.app import App
from time import time
from kivy.clock import Clock
from collections import deque
from numpy import median

class Screen(RelativeLayout):

    durations_ms = deque(maxlen=100)
    last_event_loop_time = time()
    counter = 1

    @staticmethod
    def event_loop(dt):
        duration_ms = (time() - Screen.last_event_loop_time) * 1000
        Screen.durations_ms.append(duration_ms)
        Screen.last_event_loop_time = time()
        if Screen.counter == 0:
            print("Interval time (ms) median: {0:.3f}, min: {1:.3f}, max: {2:.3f}"
                  .format(median(Screen.durations_ms), min(Screen.durations_ms), max(Screen.durations_ms)))
        Screen.counter = (Screen.counter + 1) % 100

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval_free(self.event_loop, 0.010)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

The output is:

```
Interval time (ms) median: 0.035, min: 0.030, max: 1.431
Interval time (ms) median: 0.061, min: 0.030, max: 0.408
Interval time (ms) median: 0.037, min: 0.031, max: 0.551
```

Comment: Don't have an answer, but note that the clock resolution is a function of `maxfps`. Even though the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#free-clock) says "the event is free from the fps because it’s not fps limited", the events are still subject to the resolution of the clock. To see that effect, try  different values of `maxfps` without changing anything else.

Comment: Ok, I made some tests: 30 fps: 0.03ms, 40fps: 1.7ms, 50fps: 3.3ms, 60fps: 4.5ms, 70fps: 7ms, 80fps: 7.5ms, 90fps: 7.9ms, 100fps: 8.2ms, 200fps: 8.4ms. I would like to stay at 25fps though since the app performs some heavy graphics computation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem piqued my interest. I suggest using a different approach to scheduling your `event_loop` using the Python `sched` module. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.read("config.ini")
Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '25')
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'free_all')
Config.write()

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.app import App
import sched
from time import time, sleep
from collections import deque
from numpy import median

class Screen(RelativeLayout):

    durations_ms = deque(maxlen=100)
    last_event_loop_time = time()
    counter = 1
    s = sched.scheduler(time, sleep)  # create the scheduler

    def event_loop(self):
        duration_ms = (time() - Screen.last_event_loop_time) * 1000
        Screen.last_event_loop_time = time()
        Screen.durations_ms.append(duration_ms)
        if Screen.counter == 0:
            print("Interval time (ms) median: {0:.3f}, min: {1:.3f}, max: {2:.3f}"
                  .format(median(Screen.durations_ms), min(Screen.durations_ms), max(Screen.durations_ms)))
        Screen.counter = (Screen.counter + 1) % 100

        # enter the next call to event_loop into the scheduler
        Screen.s.enter(0.01, 1, self.event_loop)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # enter the first call to event_loop and start the scheduler
        Screen.s.enter(0.01, 1, self.event_loop)
        Screen.s.run()


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Note that this runs your `event_loop` on the main thread. If your `event_loop` is doing GUI updates, this is good, otherwise it is very bad.

If your GUI is suffering as a result of this running on the main thread, you can run it on another thread using this version:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.read("config.ini")
Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '25')
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'free_all')
Config.write()

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.app import App
import sched
from time import time, sleep
from collections import deque
from numpy import median
import threading


class Screen(RelativeLayout):

    durations_ms = deque(maxlen=100)
    last_event_loop_time = time()
    counter = 1

    def run_event_loop(self):
        self.s = sched.scheduler(time, sleep)
        self.s.enter(0.01, 1, self.event_loop)
        self.s.run()

    def event_loop(self):
        duration_ms = (time() - Screen.last_event_loop_time) * 1000
        Screen.last_event_loop_time = time()
        Screen.durations_ms.append(duration_ms)
        if Screen.counter == 0:
            print("Interval time (ms) median: {0:.3f}, min: {1:.3f}, max: {2:.3f}"
                  .format(median(Screen.durations_ms), min(Screen.durations_ms), max(Screen.durations_ms)))
        Screen.counter = (Screen.counter + 1) % 100
        self.s.enter(0.01, 1, self.event_loop)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_event_loop, daemon=True).start()


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am not sure. I have no clue how to force GUI updates and suppose that doing this manually is probably causing some effects. I found that async support is currently being integrated into Kivy (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/6368/). I will try it out - it sounds like the way to go.

Comment: By "doing GUI Updates" I meant things like moving Widgets, changing `Label` text, changing colors, etc. The normal `App` event loop will handle the usual GUI updates (at 25 fps). If your `event_loop` is not making GUI changes, then you should consider moving it to another thread. otherwise it may use up cpu cycles that the normal `App` event loop needs.

Comment: I see, it's just when I tested your solution the Kivy window did not even come up. It seems to be blocked and that's why I supposed one needs to force the GUI somehow.

Comment: That suggests that your `event_loop` is taking too much time on the main thread. I have added a version of my answer that uses a separate thread. (Note that the GUI should not be manipulated from the new thread).